# SQL: Loop single select vs one select with IN clause

Tags: sql, loops

I'd like to ask you what is faster if use

1. Loop array and 
       call select XXX where id=
2. Call select XXX where id IN (list value of array)

Comment: Probably alternative 2. Let the server do it in one single call.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) and report back your findings.

Comment: It'll depend on the DBMS you connect to but most likely the second option. You can batch more records per TCP/IP call assuming you don't have a fetch size of 1. Also the DBMS might hold some resource locks while processing those queries, by batching the results with the IN clause you would avoid possible lock overhead.

Comment: 99.9% probabbilty for #2

Comment: Best practice is to avoid as much as possible Database calls to reduce cost and increase log visibility if you need to debug or audit. Doing select in a loop is really poor performance.

Comment: Also try option 3.  `where 1=2, start loop, or id = array value, stop loop`.

Answer (score 4):

The second one is *almost* always faster. Remember that in the first option, the client (usually) has to do a full database connection, log in, send the query, wait for the query to get parsed, wait for the query to get optimized, wait for the query to execute and then wait for the result to get back. In the second option, all of these steps are done once.

There may be cases where the first option is actually faster **if** your index-schema is bad and can't be fixed or the server is **seriously** wrong about how to run the disjunction that is the `IN`-clause and can't be told otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Doing all the work in the database should always be faster.  Each time you connect to the database you incur some overhead.  This overhead might be relatively minor, if the query plan is cached and the cache is optimized, but the data still needs to go back and forth.

More importantly, database engines are optimized to run queries.  Some databases optimize `in` expressions, using a binary lookup.  Parallel databases can also take advantage of multiple processors for the query.  The performance only gets worse if the `from` is a view or if your query is more complicated.

Under some conditions, the performance difference may not really be noticeable -- say for a local database where the table is cached in memory.  However, your habit should be to do such work in the database, not in the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon Linoff, It really help me understanding.